# Ontology Failing to Save Changes -- Error = OntologyMetadata:ObjectTypesReferenceDeletedInlineActionTypes

Tags: palantir-foundry

I've been working with an object in Palantir Foundry (still in experimental status, as I've been adjusting and developing based on feedback). Recently I went to change a field from a string to a string array and started running into this error (see image below) when trying to update the properties in the Ontology Manager.

[image]

Then I realized that pretty much anything I try to edit on the object (including permissions on certain actions), I get this error too. I've made changes and updates to the ontology previously without any issue, last successful edit was around 3 weeks ago (even if it meant getting rid of any test data due to schema updates, etc.).

I noticed recently that Palantir had some info/tips on "new" functionality with "inline edits" but didn't pay much attention to them, thinking it shouldn't impact anything I've already built (and now those tips are gone from view).

I've looked at documentation to try and find information about this error, and have tried changing the actions and other settings to see if there was any clear conflict I could resolve, but haven't found anything on my end that I can change that seems to get this working again.

Any thoughts on this error and steps I can take or investigate to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried to find the object type with that ID and disassociate the action?

Comment: I did try to search on the ID the error was referencing, but the search came up empty -- which I thought was pretty strange. 

What is stranger is that today when I tried to double check this finding (by recreating the error and searching the ID again) the error seems to have gone away. I was able to successfully edit the object again -- I'm not sure what changed this weekend but feels like #spookyseason stuff to me. 

I'll take the magical fix I guess!